# TextField Multiline Form allows text larger than box

Tags: forms

What i'm worried about is printing out a filled out Form where simple multiline TextFields have been filled out but most of the content is invisible because the box was too small.
Ideally the height of the box would automatically adjust. 
My quickfix was using maxlen=100 to limit the number of letters - but if the user chooses to hit return  a few times, this wont work.

any ideas?

Comment: Does this question belong here at all?

Answer (score 0):

I think your question belongs on the https://stackoverflow.com/ website, rather than in the TeX section.

In any case, I suggest that instead of printing the input box, either use javascript or something on the server side to generate a page with the form's text rendered inside a `<pre></pre>` block or something similar.

Please ask follow-up questions about this at https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: thanks, i habe moved the question there. 
Well, i started writing a Perlscript and getting the form input via Email. It adds complexity though on the user-end, which i'd prefer to avoid.